# OL application is at different production server than GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, windows, linux

My OL ASP.Net web application is hosted at 172.24.100.16 production server (windows server 2008)whereas Geoserver is hosted at 172.24.100.15 production server (Linux, UBUNTU). When i access page from outside the production environment, then Layers does not show over google map in page.

I need suggestion to fix this problem. Also, i need explanation why it happen ?

Comment: Setup up xDomain and Proxyhost - http://cartoninjas.net/post/2010/11/24/ASPNET-xDomainProxy-for-OpenLayers-getInfo-requests.aspx - via IIS 7x

Comment: Or IISProxy - http://geographika.co.uk/a-proxy-for-iis-and-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of crossdomain ajax problem with Geoserver WMS XMLhttp request. To fix this the geoserver and IIS(In case of ASP) should be in same domain.You need to set up proxy to access geoserver frm IIS .Otherwise you have to write your own proxy.
visit:
http://khayer.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/open-layer-with-geosever/#comment-367